# Why my crontab not working using wget command?

Tags: php, cron, wget

When i run my url `https://localhost/panel/index.php?m=user_games&p=check_expire` by using chrome the code is run and shutting down the server when expier.

But when i need to run this as a `crontab` using this command:

```
* * * * * * wget -q --spider "https://localhost/panel/index.php?m=user_games&p=check_expire"
```

nothing happend, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem the crontab not run, because you define wrong crontab command. You put six `*`, as I know we just need five `*`. Please try like this

```
* * * * * wget -q --spider "https://localhost/panel/index.php?m=user_games&p=check_expire"
```

To make sure your `crontab` run, please create log when `wget` executed.